# How to convert floating point number in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

How to convert floating point number to base-16 numbers, 8 hexadecimal digits per 32-bit FLP number in python?

eg : `input = 1.2717441261e+20 output wanted : 3403244E`

Comment: How is this output derived?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the byte values of the IEEE-754 representation, the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module can do this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> f = 1.2717441261e+20
>>> struct.pack('f', f)
'\xc9\x9c\xdc`'
```

This is a string version of the bytes, which can then be converted into a string representation of the hex values:

```
>>> struct.pack('f', f).encode('hex')
'c99cdc60'
```

And, if you want it as a hex integer, parse it as such:

```
>>> s = struct.pack('f', f).encode('hex')
>>> int(s, 16)
3382500448
```

To display the integer as hex:

```
>>> hex(int(s, 16))
'0xc99cdc60'
```

Note that this does not match the hex value in your question -- if your value is the correct one you want, please update the question to say how it is derived.

Comment: To make the code work with Python 3, use `codecs.encode(pack('f', f), 'hex')` instead.

Comment: As of python3.5 it looks like the bytes object contains a `hex()` method, and so the first example above can be simplified to `struct.pack('f', f).hex()`

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible ways to do so, but none of them leads to the result you wanted.

- You can code this float value into its IEEE binary representation. This leads indeed to a 32 bit number (if you do it with single precision). But it leads to different results, no matter which endianness I suppose:

  ```
  import struct
  struct.pack("<f", 1.2717441261e+20).encode("hex")
  # -> 'c99cdc60'
  struct.pack(">f", 1.2717441261e+20).encode("hex")
  # -> '60dc9cc9'

  struct.unpack("<f", "3403244E".decode("hex"))
  # -> (687918336.0,)
  struct.unpack(">f", "3403244E".decode("hex"))
  # -> (1.2213533295835077e-07,)
  ```
- As the other one didn't fit result-wise, I'll take the other answers and include them here:

  ```
  float.hex(1.2717441261e+20)
  # -> '0x1.b939919e12808p+66'
  ```

  Has nothing to do with `3403244E` as well, so maybe you want to clarify what exactly you mean.

There are surely other ways to do this conversation, but unless you specify which method you want, no one is likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `float.hex(input)`. This should convert a number into a string representing the number in base 16, and works with floats, unlike `hex()`. The string will begin with `0x` however, and will contain 13 digits after the decimal point, so I can't help you with the 8 digits part.

Source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex

Comment: Ya. only for integers

Comment: How is that number being converted into 3403244E? I'm not understanding that, maybe I'll be able to answer the question properly then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your expected output :

```
import struct
input = 1.2717441261e+20
buf = struct.pack(">f", input)
print ''.join("%x" % ord(c) for c in struct.unpack(">4c", buf) )
```

Output :

```
60dc9cc9
```

Comment: @user2601010 It depends on how you pack and unpack the bytes, but I don't know how you get the output you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try `float.hex(input)` if `input` is already a float.